# Web service client cannot be created error

Tags: java, soap, netbeans, wsdl

[image]

I am making a currency converter using netbeans, using a wdsl/soap
http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net/converter.asmx?op=GetConversionAmount

Whenever i try to retrieve the information i get the error shown on the picture above, does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: this commend comes with JDK package so you have this commend.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not using Netbeans so I cannt tell about the perticular issue.
But if you want to generate the client side code for webservice.
Just run the following commend

wsimport -keep wsdlUrl

for wsdl url deploy your application and open in browser the copy the url from browser.
this will generate all the source code for client java file as well as .class files.
wsimport commend has many other options check if you want more.

Comment: this commend comes with JDL package. 
for testing purpose create a temp dir at your desktop.
open commend prompt goto to your folder and run the commend
here is a test URL: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Comment: and run the commend:
wsimport -keep http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL